# Button transition without hover

Tags: css

I created a button that when i pass on it with the mouse it lights up in all colors, because i set the hover property.

But I would like this button to light up indefinitely without hover.

My button code:

```
function FirstPositionButton() {
return (
<Link to='Pay'>  
<div className="fix">
  <button className="btn2">Reach the 1° position!!</button>  
</div>      
</Link>
)}
```

My css code:

```
.btn2 {
 padding: 6px 18px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 outline: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 2px solid;
 animation: rotate 0.4s linear both infinite;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #fff;
 }

 @keyframes rotate {
 100%{
  filter: hue-rotate(-360deg)
 }}

 .btn2:hover{
  padding: 6px 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary);
  }
```

I've tried to delete the hover or to put the transition inside the btn2 but nothing appeared, so how could i fix that issue? thanks!!

Comment: A transition occurs when changing *state*. If you want this effect without any interaction you just need the **animation** on the default state.

Comment: not doable without JS. You need JS with an `onmouseover` trigger to achieve what you want. Otehrwise with hover it will stop asoon as yous top to hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you define the `--secondary`... And what is the value. Do you have something like this?

```css
body{
  background: black;
  --secondary: green;
}

.btn2 {
  padding: 6px 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
  animation: rotate 0.4s linear both infinite;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(-360deg)
  }
}

.btn2:hover {
  padding: 6px 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary);
}
```

```html
<div class="fix">
  <button class="btn2"> Reach the 1° position!! </button>
</div>
```

The only difference between the `.btn` rule and the `.btn:hover` rule, by the way, is that border color... And maybe the `transition` property which has no effect.

```css
body{
  background: black;
  --secondary: green;
}

.btn2 {
  padding: 6px 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary);
  animation: rotate 0.4s linear both infinite;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fix">
  <button class="btn2"> Reach the 1° position!! </button>
</div>
```

That is more fun aplied on a text color too!

Notice that the filter seems to apply on colors which have different `r`, `g` and `b` parameters... So does not visually do the effect for colors like `#000`, `#fff`, `#aaa`, and so on...

```css
body{
  background: black;
  --secondary: green;
}

.btn2 {
  padding: 6px 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary);
  animation: rotate 0.4s linear both infinite;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #bc34e8;  /* Whatever color... */
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(-360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fix">
  <button class="btn2"> Reach the 1° position!! </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u this was the solution that i was searching, anyway the (--secondary) was a color that i defined in :root , but finally it works, thank u!